# How to initialize a bean using a mule global property

Tags: spring, mule

I have a bean which I want to initialize from a global property

```
<global-property name="logging.prefix" value="#[message.id]-Task-#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.TaskId] - " doc:name="Global Property"/>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="MyBean" name="MyBean" class="com.my.bean" >
        <spring:constructor-arg index="0" type="String" name="logPrefix" value="${logging.prefix}">
            <spring:description>Logging prefix</spring:description>
        </spring:constructor-arg>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

When my bean is constructed, I get the string literal of the MEL expression. When I reference ${logging.prefix} inside a flow, I get the evaluated MEL. Is there a way for me to initialize my bean without repeating the MEL expression in my bean constructor and the global property?

I've tried #[${logging.prefix}] which also didn't work.

EDIT

I tried duplicating the MEL expression in the value attribute of the bean constructor and this also passes in the literal

```
<spring:constructor-arg index="0" type="String" name="logPrefix" value="#[message.id]-Task-#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.TaskId] - ">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm not thinking - the message only exists within the scope of my workflow which explains why I can't access it at the global level.

So the solution is to pass the MEL expression in as a parameter to the function being called on my bean.